# How can I show server response messages using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I am able to validate my form following the docs for length and such, but I would also like to show the response I am getting back from my server.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
public sendResetCode(): void {
...
    onFailure: (err: any) => {
        this.requestActive = false;
        console.log(err.message);
        if (err.code === "MyErrorException") {
            this.message = err.message;
        }

        this.$scope.$apply();
    },
}
...
```

Here is what my template looks like:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input name="email" ng-model="vm.email" required md-maxlength="50" minlength="6">
    <div ng-messages="myForm.email.$error">
        {{ resetEmailForm.email.$error }}
    <div ng-message="required">Your Email Address is required.</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your Email Address is too short.</div>
    <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Your Email Address is too long</div>
    <div ng-message="???">{{ vm.message }}</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: do u get any errors? or what

Comment: What do you use for HTTP communication? Where do you put this onFailure handler?

Comment: @Aravind Yes - I can see in the network tab what I'm getting back. I can do `ng-show="vm.message"` and show the message - but I'm trying to show it the same way everything else is

Comment: @TamasHegedus `onFailure` is in my controller. I've updated the question to show more context of that.